# AngularJS routeprovider won't do anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to check before every page load if his session is active, if not, redirect to the login page.
This is my App.js

```
var app = angular.module('Test', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .otherwise({
            resolve:
            {
                "checkUserSession": function($q,$http,$window)
                {
                    console.log('start of the def')
                    var deffered = $q.defer();
                    $http.get('/general/php/getCurrentUser.php')
                        .then(function(result)
                        {
                            if(!result)
                            {
                                deffered.reject();
                                $window.location.href = "/";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                deffered.resolve();
                            }
                        });
                    $window.location.href = "/";

                    return deffered.promise;
                }
            }
        })
});
```

And it won't execute the console.log, the $http.get() or any of the redirects.
It doesn't matter if the promise is resolved or rejected, it looks likes the "checkUserSession" won't ever execute;

Every page includes the angular-route.js script.

Comment: why are you doing `$window.location.href`?

Comment: To redirect the user to the login page if it's not logged. But looks like it's not entering the checkUserSession.

Answer (score 0):

**Use an interceptor.**

In my case I check for the authentication token in local storage but you could use your session logic here.

Start with `angular.module(...).config` -

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('BearerAuthInterceptor');
...
```

Then use a service as following:

```
.factory('BearerAuthInterceptor', function ($q, $injector, $window) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        var tk = $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (tk) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + tk;
        } 
        return config || $q.when(config);
    },
    response: function (response) {
        return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function (rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
    // Redirect to login ui-route
            $injector.get('$state').go('login');
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
})
```

Some good examples here: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/